# How do I get all apps in an Activity to use a specific network connection?

Tags: networking, kubuntu

I have two internet connections that I want to be able to use, but one of them is for work specifically. I was wondering if it was at all possible to make it so I have an activity that uses one network device / connection, and the other use the default connection.

I have a wired connection for my home, and a wireless connection that is preconfigured to be a company VPN. The wireless connection is *dreadfully slow* sometimes, and swapping internet connections manually every time I want to utilize each network for what I need it for is a pain.

Ideally, I would like to have 1 activity where everything on it automatically knows to use the wireless connection, and the other activity knows to use the wired connection (since both can be connected at the same time). If activities are not a way to solve this, is there a way to say "X application's network traffic goes through Y device"?

This is my screenfetch output in case it is helpful.

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04 focal
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.4.0-122-generic
Uptime: 56m
Packages: 3273
Shell: zsh 5.8
Resolution: 2560x1440
DE: KDE 5.68.0 / Plasma 5.18.8
WM: KWin
GTK Theme: Breeze [GTK2/3]
Icon Theme: breeze-dark
Disk: 117G / 261G (47%)
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3800X 8-Core @ 16x 3.9GHz
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER
RAM: 4682MiB / 64281MiB
```

I don't think that there's a solution to this and that I'll need to write a script or something for it. If anyone knows a solution, that would be fabulous!

Answer (score 0):

The task, in my opinion, does not have a simple solution.

### Warning

Before you examine the proposed solutions presented, please make sure that the slowness of the connection and applications is not caused by the **problem of the two default gateways on your computer**.

Unfortunately, it often happens that a computer has two default gateways working at the same time in one basic routing table for two network interfaces. This is regularly a source of trouble, accidental connection dropouts, communication slowdowns, etc. So-called asymmetric routing may occur. Sometimes one of the two interfaces stops working completely. To check, use the command:

```
ip route
```

There should not be a situation where there are two lines containing the word **default** in the command output:

```
default via 10.1.1.1 dev eth1 proto dhcp metric 100 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp metric 600
```

Exceptions are special situations where the user in the role of an interface administrator knows what he is doing and why.

The following proposal does not describe a solution for the two default gateways problem, but for a situation where there is only one default gateway and routing is incorrectly set for some remote destination networks or individual addresses.

### Option 1: Modify routing

#### 1a: Get information

Find out the destination IP addresses and networks that your business applications communicate with.

A command to display a **routing table** will help you.

```
ip route
```

In the list, you'll find paths that send packets to the VPN tunnel and others that aren't related to the tunnel. Those tunnel routes have the name of the tunnel interface in them, for example `tun0`:

Example of **"tunnel" routes**:

```
10.88.0.0/13 dev tun0 scope link
10.150.80.0/24 dev tun0 scope link
```

Example of **non-tunnel routes**:

```
default via 10.1.1.1 dev eth1 proto dhcp metric 100
10.1.1.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.1.110 metric 100
```

Another way how to find company addresses is to use the Wireshark, capture network data, and look at pairs of addresses that communicate with each other. One address will always be with you on your PC and the other will be remote. You have 2 connections, these are two local addresses, so you will need to capture data on both interfaces with two instances of Wireshark.

Examples of company (work) applications and destinations:

- Mail server
- File server
- Company web portal
- Directory controllers and services
- Etc.

You will probably find that you only access certain networks through a VPN (e.g. 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/1) and all other communication goes outside the VPN, i.e. out into the Internet.

Please be aware that when the VPN tunnel starts, new routes are added to the system and the solution must take this into account.

#### 1b: Change the routing and test your connections

Modify routing rules. The original list of routes was obtained with the `ip route` command mentioned above. New paths must be set up so that anything that should not go through the VPN tunnel is routed out through the main fast interface.

#### 1c: Make the changes persistent or easy re-applicable

Commands that change routing rules must be written to a script (e.g. a simple bash script). You will then run the script every time after a VPN tunnel connection is established to the company. Modified routing could speed up the operation of those services and applications that communicate through the tunnel, but are not actually corporate, do not need the tunnel and can go directly to the Internet.

### Option 2: Separate both the applications and the connections of 2 machines

Install virtualization platform (VMware, VirtualBox...) and create new virtual machine (VM) in your PC.

Ensure in host and guest (VM) settings that the business applications and their communication is concentrated in a virtual machine that will use only a wireless connection, and other non-business applications are either on the host or in the second virtual machine, and communication takes place via a fast interface. The VPN tunnel will then start on the first virtual machine and its data will pass through the VPN tunnel and the wireless interface.

Comment: Hey, just want you to know that I have seen you responded and will be reviewing this in detail by Monday or Tuesday. Thank you for your response!